# TwoSum solution only works for one input

Tags: python

I am a beginner, and for some reason my method below is wrong. The first input yields a right answer but not the second. The question is: Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        for i in nums:
            for j in nums:
                if i+j == target or j+i == target:
                    indexi = nums.index(i)
                    indexj = nums.index(j)
                    return [indexi, indexj]
```

```
Your input
 [2,7,11,15]
     9
 [3,2,4]
     6
Output
  [0,1]
  [0,0]
Expected
  [0,1]
  [1,2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that's happening in your second example is that `i` and `j` can be the same number - as both loop over the `nums` array independently.

A simple way to avoid this is to loop over the indices, and start `j` from after `i`. This will also avoid going over each pair twice:

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
            if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
                return [i, j]
```

(Note that I've also removed the pointless checking of the same thing twice in the `if` statement. I also don't see why this needs to be a method of a class, as opposed to a regular function, since `self` is not referred to anywhere. But it might make sense depending on what the rest of your class does, which you don't share.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it added the first index twice. Your code doesn't prohibit the software from doing this. You should instead try:

```
for i in len(nums):
            for j in len(nums):
                if i != j and nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                    return [i, j]
```

This checks that you're not adding the index to itself.